# Empty result from aws configure get aws_access_key_id

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell-2.0

I currently have an AWS cli profile set up that I can query using the below powershell command:

```
aws configure list --profile <ProfileName>
```

This returns the expected info about profile name, access_key and so on.

However, when trying to get just the access key, I get nothing back. The command I am running is `aws configure get aws_access_key_id --profile <ProfileName>`

What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

```
aws iam list-access-keys
```

Try to use this command. It should work.